# Looking for Hash Function

Tags: math, random, hash, random-seed, hash-function

I am looking for a hash function with the following properties

1. It maps an arbitrary string uniformly between 0 and 1
2. The hash function output is independent of the length of the string
3. The hash function accepts a random seed
4. For a given random seed the mapping from string to (0,1) is deterministic meaning if Alice and Bob calculate the hash for a given string and random seed they will both get the same value
5. I am not worried about security. I don’t care if someone in theory could reconstruct the set of strings given random seed and hash value

Would be great to get some ideas.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what nr. 2 actually mean? Do you mean that the string length does not impact the output? What about performance relative to length?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using a bunch of programming language so I am more looking for pseudo code.

Comment: I am not concerned about performance at all actually. I am a data scientist so we are not running the code in production. Your statement is correct. I am looking for a mapping f(string) -> [0,1] so that the function is independent of the length of the string.

Comment: This does not seem too hard. For example, take any hash function H(x) that maps strings uniformly into, say, a 64-bit integer. Then H(r || x) / 2\**64, where r is a random number, will be a hash function with the 5 properties you've listed.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't like this 'solution' explain why not and you'll get better answers.

Take the ASCII code table and throw away the codes for non-characters such as 'bell', you'll be left with approximately 100 characters.

Make a 1:1 mapping between characters and 2-digit numbers, eg you might start with

```
space <-> 00
! <-> 01
A <-> 33
...
Z <-> 58
...
a <-> 65
```

I expect you get the picture.  Now, encode the first 32 (or whatever) characters in your string in the obvious way, eg

```
`Aa aa` -> `3365006565`
```

and pad any strings shorter than 32-characters with `00`.  (I couldn't be bothered typing all the `00` for the example.)

Generate a random number in the range `[1,64]` and use that to rotate the numeric string left by that number of places.

Slap a decimal point on the front of what is left and you have the sought-for real number.

I believe that this satisfies your requirements.

Comment: I like your idea! The problem is that is violates number 2. namely that the output is independent of the length of the string. Becuase when you pad your sequence with 0s and then randomly rotate them around then the shorter the string the more 0s and thus the more likely that the 0s will be in the front. I am wondering if you can solve it by just not padding.

Comment: This isn't going to work very well for non-English character sets.

Comment: Also, there are only 15 to 17 significant digits in a double-precision floating point number. So strings that are identical in the first 8 or 9 characters will hash to the same value. It's unlikely that this hashing function would result in a uniform distribution.